# Determine the probability that distance between roots of the equation $x^2+mx+n=0$ is not greater then $1$.

Tags: probability

> Suppose that $m,n$ be real number randomly choosen from $[0,1]$.Determine the probability that distance between roots of the equation $x^2+mx+n=0$ is not greater then $1$.

What I try : Here Total ways $= $ Area of formed  formed by $[1,1]$ , Which is $1$

And here $A(\alpha,f(\alpha))$ and $B(\beta,f(\beta)),$ Where $f(x)=x^2+mx+n$

Here$\alpha+\beta=-m$ and $\alpha\beta=n$.

Then We have to find

$\displaystyle \sqrt{(\beta-\alpha)^2+(f(\beta)-f(\alpha))^2}\leq 1$

$\displaystyle \sqrt{(\beta-\alpha)^2+(\beta^2-\alpha^2)^2+m^2(\beta-\alpha)^2}\leq 1$

$\displaystyle |\beta-\alpha|\sqrt{1-m+m^2}\leq 1$

$\displaystyle \sqrt{m^2-4n}\sqrt{1+m+m^2}\leq 1$

How do I find favourable case, Please have a look on that problem, Thanks

Comment: By definition of "roots", $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)=0$

Comment: Why don't you simply calculate $\mathbb{P}(|\alpha - \beta | \le )$?

Comment: In the question, how does $\alpha, \beta$ impact $m, n$?

Comment: My read, which I believe concurs with user469053 and NN2 (but might still be wrong) is that you want $ \alpha , \beta$ to be the roots of the equation, which is why you can just look at $P ( |\alpha - \beta| \leq 1 ) = 1$. $\quad$ It's very different if you're asking for roots of $ x^2 + \alpha x + \beta = 0 $. $\quad$ In particular, neither of this is like what you wrote, hence the request for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots of $X^2+mX+n$ are
$$ \alpha_{\pm}=\frac{-m\pm\sqrt{m^2-4n}}{2} $$
so $\alpha_+-\alpha_-=\sqrt{m^2-4n}\in\mathbf{C}$. The probability you want to compute is
$$ \begin{aligned} \mathbf{P}(|\alpha_+-\alpha_-|\leqslant 1) &= \mathbf{P}(|m^2-4n|\leqslant 1) \\
&=\mathbf{P}\left(\frac{m^2-1}{4}\leqslant n\leqslant\frac{m^2+1}{4}\right) \\
&=\int_0^1\mathbf{P}\left(\frac{t^2-1}{4}\leqslant n\leqslant\frac{t^2+1}{4}\right)dt \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{t^2+1}{4}dt \,(\text{because } t^2-1\leqslant 0) \\
&=\frac{1}{3}. \end{aligned} $$

Comment: $m=-S$ (the sum of the roots), while $n=P$ (the product). Hence, as $|a-b|=\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4ab}$, you can easily see that this should be $\sqrt{m^2-4n}$.